# Apply image change on page load rather than click

Tags: jquery, image

I have a product browse page on a shopping site which displays a list of product images.

Some products have colour options, and the images for these colour options can be displayed by clicking on a relevant coloured box. The main product image is then swapped for the relevant coloured product image.

I am using the below jquery code to do this swapping of product images, plus pass a hover image url which is displayed when hovering the image (done with some different code)

```
// change browse image on child colour box click
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('div[child-image]').click(function(event) {
        jQuery('img[id~=product-browse-image-'+event.target.id+']')
            .attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('child-image'))
            .attr('hover-image', jQuery(this).attr('child-hover-image'))
    }).each(function() {
        jQuery('<img />').attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('child-image'));
    });;
});
```

Customers can also filter the products in the store by their colour.

When this is done `&colour=RED1` for example is added to the url

I want to use this variable and switch the images based on the value 'RED1' or what ever value is showing when the page loads, so people filtering for red items, where the product has a red colour option, the red images are shown. Products just sold in red would already be showing their only images in red.

In this case the coloured box holding the relevant images, I want the replaced looks like this:

```
<div id="1" class="child-colour RED1" child-image="/images/BC_00000475_190x253.jpg" child-hover-image="/BC_00000474_190x253.jpg"></div>
```

I can get the variable value from the url ok, for the sake of this explanation it is 'value'

So I think I would need to use this at some point:

```
div[class^="child-colour '+value+'"]
```

But apart from that I have no idea of how to go about using the above code to achieve what I have explained.

Comment: Please post the associated html.

Answer (score 0):

The html code for a product with two child products options, red and blue is shown at the bottom of this post.

I want to use the 'RED1' value in the url &colour=RED1 (/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id=2&Itemid=112&cupboard_knobs_colour=multi) to force the swapping of the main product images with the values from this div

```
<div id="1" class="child-colour RED1" child-image="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000475_190x253.jpg" child-hover-image="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000474_190x253.jpg"></div>
```

i think it just needs a manipulation of the jquery  in my first post to run on document ready and to use the colour variable form the url.

-- html code below --

```
<div class="product floatleft">
    <div class="spacer">
      <div class="center">
      <div class="product-browse-image">

      <a title="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=1&amp;virtuemart_category_id=2&amp;Itemid=112" href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=1&amp;virtuemart_category_id=2&amp;Itemid=112">


        <img width="100%" id="product-browse-image-1" src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000475_190x253.jpg" hover-image="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000474_190x253.jpg" tmp="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000474_190x253.jpg">        </a>
        </div>
        <!-- The "Average Customer Rating" Part -->
                      </div>
      <div>
                <a href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=1&amp;virtuemart_category_id=2&amp;Itemid=112">Ashed Fleurs-De test</a>    



        <div class="product-price marginbottom12" id="productPrice1">
          <div class="PricesalesPrice" style="display : block;"><span class="PricesalesPrice">£28.80</span></div>        </div>
        <a class="quick-view cboxElement" href="/index.php?tmpl=modal&amp;option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=1&amp;virtuemart_category_id=2&amp;Itemid=112&amp;productlayout=quickview" rel="/index.php?tmpl=modal&amp;option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=1&amp;virtuemart_category_id=2&amp;Itemid=112&amp;productlayout=quickview">QV</a>
        <p>
          <a href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=1&amp;virtuemart_category_id=2&amp;Itemid=112" title="Ashed Fleurs-De test" class="product-details">Product details</a>                        


                                 <span class="product-field-display"></span></p><div id="1" class="child-colour BLU1" child-image="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000484_190x253.jpg" child-hover-image="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000485_190x253.jpg"></div><div id="1" class="child-colour RED1" child-image="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000475_190x253.jpg" child-hover-image="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/BC_00000474_190x253.jpg"></div>
                  <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of spacer -->
  </div>
```